# If else condition in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am doing a C# project using Selenium. and i need to check an element exists?

for an example

```
var userNameField = driver.FindElementById("id_email");
userNameField.SendKeys("xxxxx");
```

if the **userNameField** does not exist in the webpage, Some code must not work and else part must work..
is there any suggestions..?

Comment: Use `try catch`. Continue your `else` part in `catch`.

Comment: its working on try catch

Comment: but i am waiting for more possible suggetions

Comment: If your question is answered to your liking please consider marking one of the answers as the answer: [How to mark a question as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using FindElementById, you can try to go for FindElements, which will return you a list containing all the possible elements corresponding to your search. You can then test if this list is empty or not, and execute the corresponding code depending on the answer.

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.FindElements(By.Id("id_email"));
if(rows.Count > 0)
{
    // The element exists. You can work with it.
    rows.First().SendKeys("xxxxx");
}
else
{
    // The element doesn't exist.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try catch to make this work.
if the webdriver cant find an element it will throw a NoSuchElementException.

```
IWebElement userNameField = null;
try 
{
    userNameField = driver.FindElementById("id_email");
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e)
{
    // If you are creating a unit test
    Assert.Fail("Element "userNameField" not found.")
}

// If you just want the if:
if(userNameField != null)
{
    userNameField.SendKeys("xxxxx");
}
else 
{
    // do your thing
}
```